# Programmatically inject code into functions?

Tags: .net

Lets say in .NET/C# I have a bunch of static classes in a namespace. I don't want to manually change the code but I'd like to make them all call a specific function when entering a function. It would be nice if I could pass in the class/function name but not required. How might I do this?

Comment: Is this for analytical purposes or a permanent thing?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Not my call but probably a permanent thing if functions/classes can  be filtered out

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something called `Aspect Oriented Programming` or `AOP`.

Try the [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com) library

Comment: But it looks like I need to manually put `[attr]` on all of them:/

Comment: That's all i've got as far as libraries.  If you don't like that option then you can always write something to modify the code or the IL yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without modifying the source code, you will be looking at modifying the IL directly.  In fact, "PostSharp" itself does rewrite your assembly IL, as do many aspect-oriented libraries.

You could theoretically rewrite your the IL yourself, (and a project such as [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) might help) without modifying the source - however, I doubt it would be worth the effort.